# Can my router provide IP addresses with an internet received via wifi?

Tags: ip, wifi, router, dhcp

I'm using a borrowed wifi signal from my neighbour, all the devices in my apartment receive IP addresses from his router. Once I was having some connecting problems and I decided to try using what they call **static IP** addresses (big ignorant mistake), all my devices connected right away, but my neighbour came to complain. I fixed the problem, came back to asking the IP addresses via DHCP.

Can I use another router to receive his signal and provide own IP addresses to my devices?

I wish I could have internet in all my six devices but using only one slot in my neighbour's router. I tried enabling the DHCP in my router (normally disabled), it successfully provided own IP addresses to all my devices, but none of them connect to internet. The IP address of my router is 192.168.0.1, a TP-LINK router, my neighbour's is 192.168.1.1, a MERCUSYS router.

I feel like it should be an easy task, but all my attempts has failed.

Comment: Please read [ask] - this isn't a general tech helpdesk.

Comment: You should ask at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com). Here you hardly will get an answer as the question is absolutely off topic.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question “Can I use another router to receive his signal and provide own IP addresses to my devices?“ is: yes. There may be more than one way to do it, but I think that two NAT routers with a Wifi-Bridge in between will do the trick.

The Wifi-bridge can be a dedicated device or yet another router configured in bridge mode. In either way, it receives a Wifi-signal from your neighbor and has a LAN port. That LAN-port is the input to your own routers WAN interface. Let that router acquire this way one IP address from your neighbor. The Wifi that your router then provides can be used by all your devices with local IP addresses that are Independent of your neighbors IP address range.